# I don't understand why my object doesn't receive notifications

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, nsnotificationcenter

I've create a custom class that looks like:

```swift
class FooDevice: Device {

  private var controller:FooController?
  private var device:Foo?


  override init() {
    super.init()
    if super.authGranted {
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.discovered(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: FooDiscover), object: nil)
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.connected(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: FooConnected), object: nil)
    }
  }

  @objc private func discovered(_ notification:Notification) {
    DDLogVerbose("FOO - discovered - \(notification)")
    super.scanner?.stopScanFor(._FOO)
    // TODO: Call super.connector and connect
  }

  @objc private func connected(_ notification:Notification) {
    DDLogVerbose("FOO - connected - \(notification)")
    // Do more stuff after connect
  }


  func start() {
    DDLogVerbose("FOO - startMeasurement()")
    super.scanner?.scanFor(._FOO)
  }  
}
```

The super class looks like:

```swift
class Device: NSObject {

  private let LICENSE = "my_license"

  private var authenticator:SDKAuthenticator?
  internal var scanner:SDKScanner?
  internal var connector:SDKConnector?
  internal var authGranted = false


  override init() {
    super.init()
    authGranted = self.authRequest(LICENSE)
    if authGranted {
      scanner = SDKScanner.getInstance()
      connector = SDKConnector.getInstance()
    } else {
      // TODO: Show error to user
    }
  }

  private func authRequest(_ data:String) -> Bool {
    // Do stuff using authenticator and authenticated, we can assume we return a true
    return status // true
  }
}
```

In my ViewController I make an instance of `FooDevice` and start the process. I'm doing with the following:

```swift
class MyViewController:UIViewController {

 // A lot of properties
 override viewDidLoad() {
   // ViewDidLoad stuff
 }

 @IBAction func connectToDevice(_ sender: Any) {
  // Here I instantiate the object and start the scanning
  let myFooDevice = FooDevice()
  myFooDevice.start()
 }
}
```

In the console I could see how the scanner start and found the bluetooth device but the notification isn't captured and the log isn't printed. Also the notification names are right, I'm sure because the SDK return the strings.

I don't know what I'm missing. Hope you could throw some light to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that ARC will cleanup your `myFooDevice` variable before any notification can reach it.

You better store it in a property:

```
class MyViewController:UIViewController {

    var myFooDevice:FooDevice?

    override viewDidLoad() {
       // ViewDidLoad stuff
    }

    @IBAction func connectToDevice(_ sender: Any) {
        // Here I instantiate the object and start the scanning
        myFooDevice = FooDevice()
        myFooDevice!.start()
    }
}
```